# Show 1 centered x-tick with label with even (4) discrete groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

Im a bit surprissed I couldnt find the answer...but I have a boxplot with four groups but want to show 1 centerd tick on the x-axis on position 2.5....how do I do that?

```
library(ggplot2)

# Create a sample dataset
group <- rep(c("Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3", "Group 4"), each = 10)
value <- rnorm(40)
data <- data.frame(group, value)

# Create the boxplot with a single x-tick
ggplot(data, aes(x = group, y = value, fill = group)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = "test", breaks = 2.5) +
  labs(x = "", y = "Value") +
  ggtitle("Boxplot with a Single X-Tick")
```

Comment: What would that tick mean? Maybe better remove all ticks and tick labels, and only keep x label, which would be placed in the middle?

Comment: The tick means another group...so it contains 4 variables (boxplots) in 1 group (the tick)...I use the legend to explain the boxplots, not the ticks

Comment: Is this not what the axis labels are for?

Comment: Ofcourse thats possible but i want to have a tick...cause I have two of those figures next to each other. And with a tick it looks better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution here is to plot all the boxes at the fictional x position 'test', and use `position_dodge`:

```r
ggplot(data, aes(x = 'test', y = value, fill = group)) +
  geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(width = 1)) +
  labs(x = "", y = "Value") +
  ggtitle("Boxplot with a Single X-Tick")
```

[image]

An alternative that may be a little more flexible is to use custom annotations:

```r
ggplot(data, aes(x = group, y = value, fill = group)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = "test", breaks = 2.5) +
  labs(x = "", y = "Value") +
  coord_cartesian(clip = 'off') +
  annotation_custom(grid::linesGrob(x = c(0.5, 0.5), y = c(-0.01, 0))) +
  annotation_custom(grid::textGrob('test', x = 0.5, y = -0.03)) +
  ggtitle("Boxplot with a Single X-Tick")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to use a continuous scale which requires to convert your `group` variable to a `numeric`:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)

ggplot(data, aes(x = as.numeric(factor(group)), y = value, fill = group)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = "test", breaks = 2.5) +
  labs(x = "", y = "Value") +
  ggtitle("Boxplot with a Single X-Tick")
```

[image]

Comment: Would be nice not to have that vertical white guides on test, and have it under boxplots.

Comment: @zx8754 Hm. Yeah. That would be more in line with the "discrete scale" look. IMHO the easiest option would be to fake the grid lines using `geom_vline(xintercept = 1:4, color = "white")` and get rid of the defaults using `+ theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank())`.

Comment: @AllanCameron Yup, Allan. Dodging is a clever (and easier) solution to achieve the same result.